# while trying to download a file : the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to download a file from the server but i am getting this error:

**The process cannot access xxxx the file because it is being used by another process**

**This is my CODE:**

```
    string fileName="DownLoadFiles";
    string filePath = hid_filepath.Value;
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);      
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(fileName, filePath);
```

Foe ur Information:the file is not opened or not used...

Can anyone pls help me by providing whats the reason for this error and how to solve this error

Comment: Do you have the file open on the server?

Comment: for the time being my localhost is the server...

Comment: is the file you are writing to the same file as the one you are trying to download? Does the error occur on the receiving or the sending side (client or server code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(fileName, filePath);
```

There is an error in your code, there should be a target filename specified:

```
 wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(fileName, filePath),"c:\file.tmp");
```